# Connection Error issue in connect manager - Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4

[image]

My magento connect manager is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a tip to troubleshoot until you fix it.

Use [this](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) to download directly your extension then copy the files via FTP